# Is it appropriate to write code with a lot of calls to subprocess library of python

Tags: python, subprocess

I consider myself beginner at python.I'm currently writing code and it works perfectly well.
The problem is that use a lot of calls to subprocess library in order to embed linux bash commands .
This way I was able to rewrite a 1000 line code to 80 lines.
Here's some of my code:

```
if not OCRized(a):
    p0=subprocess.check_call(["pdftk",a,"burst"])
    print "splitting Pdf was successful........."
    for i in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        if (i>8):
         nameBurst="pg_00"+str(i+1)+".pdf"
        else:
         nameBurst="pg_000"+str(i+1)+".pdf"

        nameJPG="converted-"+str(i)+".jpg"

        p1=subprocess.check_call(["convert","-density","300",nameBurst,"-depth","8",nameJPG])
        print "Conversion to jpg was successful....."
        nameHocr="converted-"+str(i)
        p=subprocess.check_call(["tesseract",nameJPG,nameHocr,"-l","eng","hocr"])
        print "tesseract did the job for the ",str(i+1),"page"
        name2="page"+str(i)+".pdf"
        p2=subprocess.check_call(["bash","-c","hocr-pdf .> reconstructed.pdf "])
        print " Reconstruction is complete"
else:
        p=subprocess.check_call(["tesseract",'1.png','f1',"-l","eng"])
```

So what problems may this approach could generate?
(The code works but I'm still not convinced)

Comment: When most of your script is calling bash, it might be time to consider writing the whole thing in bash.

Comment: I thought about that but I need a lot of python funcionalities especillay calls to certain APIs

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that throws the doors open to opinionated answers, so...

The main thing to consider is: "does it work?" If yes, another question you should ask is, "how can I make it better?"

Would it make sense to make a 10 bash calls from python? Or to make 10 python calls (using `python -m <your_API_here>`) from bash? At the end of the day, you need to consider your use cases, and which approach makes more sense. Are you going to distribute this software to millions of users? Will this need to be platform independent? And so on.

---

Going by your code, it would seem a lot of your code can be further compressed with pipes if you were to implement them with bash. If you want to call certain python APIs, you can always fork a script the same way you invoke subprocess now. The main question is, is it worth the effort. Asking yourself some of the questions above may help you decide.